# Calculate data with overlapping dates in SQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 13 (I can update to 14 if that helps) and I'd like to return some rows based on data I've got.
The data I've got is a bit complex and comes from a few different tables but I don't think it matters here.

Currently I was able to create a query that returns data that looks like this:

```
  Product ID      Start          End        AvailableAmount  
 ------------ ------------- ------------- ------------------ 
           1   null          null                        2  
           1   2022-07-20    2022-07-22                  1  
           1   2022-07-24    2022-07-27                  1  
           2   null          null                        1  
           3   null          null                        5
```

Where `Start` is the start of a time period, `End` is the end of the period, `AvailableAmount` is the amount of product available in that time period. Available amount is calculated based on some other data.

I've tried summing up the `AvailableAmount` column but that does not return valid data because for time period from `2022-07-20` to `2022-07-24` `AvailableAmount` should be `1` but it's `2`.

I think I'd need to somehow separate these dates and list the amount per day, not per time period but I don't know how.

Basically, going day by day, `AvailableAmount` for product with ID 1 should be:

- 2022-07-20: 1
- 2022-07-21: 1,
- 2022-07-22: 1,
- 2022-07-23: 2,
- 2022-07-24: 1,
- 2022-07-25: 1,
- 2022-07-26: 1,
- 2022-07-27: 1,
- 2022-07-28: 2,
  ...

so if I'd to query for the product with time period `2022-07-20` to `2022-07-25` I should be able to request 1 unit of the product. Currently my implementation makes it impossible as it's summing up the amount so if my request spans over two different time periods the available amount is lower than it should be.

I've tried using gaps and islands approach but I don't think it'd work here. I've also read about multirange that was introduced in v14 but I haven't tested it yet, working on it. I've also tried using `generate_series` but that did not help me.

I don't know if that is enough information but I can provide more if needed.

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand well the row with `null, null` represents the default value for a data not present in any range; is it so? If that's the case the `generate_series()` function can expand day by day. Is the "full date range" just a parameter?

Comment: I actually found a way to not use `generate_series()` but instead used `LAG` and `LEAD` to calculate some differences between rows. I got my inspiration from another SO thread but I cannot find it now, I'll update the comment later on.